# Graphical representation in R: 2 as axes and 1 as volume

Tags: r, graphics, data-representation

everybody.

I am writing this question because I need your help to do a graphical representation in R. I would like to do a graphic as a coordinate system (two variables) and another variable representing the volume (size) of the points.

You can see an example:[pxfolioplotbcgmatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhn9J.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `?symbols` function

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 5:1
r <- seq(2, 10, 2)

symbols(x, y, circles=r, fg="white", bg="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You. As soon as I could I try it.